# Xserver nvidia configuration for 10.10

Tags: nvidia, server, xorg

Tried to configure and crashed Graphic interface at start-up. now stuck with no 3D

Comment: Is this on a server, or a desktop?

Comment: Information on what kind of nvidia card would help here too.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that you have caused the machine to use the backup nouvou or vga drivers if your nvidia configuration failed.

You need to reassert the old xorg configuration:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Then restart your computer to take effect. If you don't solve this issue wit this, please post your configuration and your dmesg log. Also consider posting a bug report as to why you needed to configure nvidia in such a way as to potentially make it fail.